# SSRS program flow for 'Yes' 'No' 'Other'

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm creating an SSRS report and have three Date fields.

**StartDate
TargetDate
CompleteDate**

In my report I want to create a calculated field with a few conditions to determine if the Target Dates have been met.

1. `If CompleteDate <= TargetDate then "Yes", "No"`
2. `If CompleteDate is NULL but TargetDate has not exceeded current date then "Pending","No"`
   (ie, startdate was `01/01/2019` and targetdate is `20/03/2019`)

Edit 1*

`IIF(Fields!CompleteDate.Value <= Fields!TargetDate.Value, "Yes",
    IIF(Fields!CompleteDate.Value Is Nothing AND Fields!TargetDate.Value < Now(), "Pending", "No")`

This returns "No" or "Pending" even if the TargetDate has been met.

Edit 2*

`IIF((Format(Fields!CompleteDate.Value,"dd-MM-yyyy") <= (Format(Fields!TargetDate.Value,"dd-MM-yyyy"), "Yes",
      IIF(Fields!CompleteDate.Value Is Nothing AND Fields!TargetDate.Value < Now(), "Pending,"No")`

Error in regards to "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIF' accepts this number of arguments." Is there a bracket misplacement?

**Edit 3*   @Sentinel - The Switch expression worked perfect**

`=Switch( NOT isNothing(Fields!CompleteDate.Value) AND
         Fields!CompleteDate.Value <= Fields!TargetDate.Value, "Completed On-Time"
       , NOT isNothing(Fields!CompleteDate.Value) AND
         Fields!CompleteDate.Value >  Fields!TargetDate.Value, "Completed Late"
       , isNothing(Fields!StartDate.Value), "Not Started"
       , Fields!TargetDate.Value > Now(), "In Progress"
       , Fields!TargetDate.Value <= Now(), "Running Late"
       , TRUE, "Other")`

Thanks @Sentinel, @Steve-o169 I very much appreciate it

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: IIF(Fields!CompleteDate.Value <= (Fields!TargetDate.Value),true,false)
                                                                                                                    =IIF(IsNothing(Fields!CompleteDate.Value),False,True)

Comment: Would you mind [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55241679/edit) that expression into your question?

Comment: For EDIT 2: Remove a parenthesis before each FORMAT and add one at the end of the expression to make it work. Change the date format to yyyyMMdd to compare string dates correctly - if they are both dates, no need for FORMAT.

Comment: Playing devils advocate here - this smells a lot like business logic, are you sure this shouldn't be performed in a different layer than the reporting like in the application generating this data or failing that the database itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SWITCH` function which:

> Evaluates a list of expressions and returns an Object value corresponding to the first expression in the list that is true.

```
=Switch( NOT isNothing(Fields!CompleteDate.Value) AND
         Fields!CompleteDate.Value <= Fields!TargetDate.Value, "Completed On-Time"
       , NOT isNothing(Fields!CompleteDate.Value) AND
         Fields!CompleteDate.Value >  Fields!TargetDate.Value, "Completed Late"
       , isNothing(Fields!StartDate.Value), "Not Started"
       , Fields!TargetDate.Value > Now(), "In Progress"
       , Fields!TargetDate.Value <= Now(), "Running Late"
       , TRUE, "Other")
```

You can adjust your logical expressions and string values according to your needs. Just remember that the first expression that evaluates to `TRUE` wins.  In my sample test I had `NULL` `CompleteDates` in my data and when compared to non null `TargetDates`, they evaluated as `TRUE` instead of `FALSE` hence the `NOT isNothing()`s in the first two tests. If your `TargetDate`s can be null you may need to check that condition in your logic statements as well.

Answer (score 0):

So there isn't typically a `NULL` value when it gets to SSRS.  You'll need to compare to `Nothing` to get the result you need.  In the same conditional statement, you'll want to compare `TargetDate` to `Now()` which will give you the current time.  So the expression for 2 would be something like the following.

```
=IIF(Fields!CompleteDate.Value Is Nothing AND Fields!TargetDate.Value <= Now(), "Pending", "No")
```

So if I'm understanding correctly, you want all of this in a single expression.  If so, that should look like the following.

```
=IIF(Fields!CompleteDate.Value <= Fields!TargetDate.Value, "Yes",
    IIF(Fields!CompleteDate.Value Is Nothing AND Fields!TargetDate.Value < Now(), "Pending", "No")
```

You may need to format the dates to match in the expression, depending on how your date values are coming in from the database.  Something like `Format(Fields!TargetDate.Value,”dd-MM-yyyy”) < Format(Now(),”dd-MM-yyyy”)` would probably do the trick.

EDIT: Based on the comment below, I'd recommend formatting the values before comparing them.  Try the following expression.

```
    =IIF((Year(Fields!CompleteDate.Value) <= Year(Fields!TargetDate.Value)) AND DatePart(DateInterval.DayOfYear, Fields!CompleteDate.Value) <= DatePart(DateInterval.DayOfYear, Fields!TargetDate.Value) , "Yes",
  IIF(Fields!CompleteDate.Value Is Nothing AND Fields!TargetDate.Value < Now(), "Pending", "No")
```

Comment: Hi Steve-O, Thanks for your input I very much appreciate it.





Yes I would ideally prefer a single expression to return the desired results.




=IIF(Fields!CompleteDate.Value <= Fields!TargetDate.Value, "Yes",
    IIF(Fields!CompleteDate.Value Is Nothing AND Fields!TargetDate.Value < Now(), "Pending", "No")




This returns either "No" or "Pending" even if the TargetDate has been met.

Comment: Just added another expression with formatting that you can try.  Seems to be always returning false for the first part of the conditional statement so I'd try formatting the dates to ensure you're comparing the same formats.

Comment: @Steve-o169 If you're going to format the Date values as strings at least format them in a canonical fashion that sorts lexicographically in the correct order.  Your format mask makes such that 31-01-2019 is > 21-12-2019 which is not the case in the classical understanding of the flow of time.

Comment: @Sentinel  apologies, my brain isn't working that well today.  You're correct, the format should be `MM-dd-yyyy` but the most correct way to do it would be to isolate the date parts starting with year, then month, and day. I'll edit later.

Comment: @Barley238 The last expression I added to the end of my answer should do what you need.  It compares the year from the two date fields and then compares the day of the year which eliminates the need to check month and day.

Comment: @Steve-o169 Still got it wrong it should by `YYYY-MM-DD` so the most significant digits are on the left. Year first, then Month, then Day, (then Hour, Minute, and second if needed)

Comment: @Sentinel my last expression does year, then day of year which should do the trick and save some complexity. Why worry about the month when you can get a value 1-365 to compare against. Didn't edit the other expression. Feel free to do so if it bothers you that much.

Comment: @Steve-o169 I was responding to your prior comment to me, not to any edits you made to your answer.